# No "committedFeaturesAdded" signal after dataProvider().addFeatures() - QGiS 2.14.8

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

I'm working on plugin updating existing shapefile by adding new features to it. And I have a problem with signal that hasn't been emitted by QGIS, when I've added features to layer, using dataProvider().addFeatures(). 
I'm pretty sure that I have defined correctly connection signal and function, when it is emitted.

```
layer.committedFeaturesAdded.connect(self.onFeaturesAdded)
```

Becasue when I add feature using tool in QGIS from Digitizing Toolbar, it works fine and function is running.

The problem is when I add features manually - using python.

```
def selectFeatures(self,diviLayer, userLayer84):
        self.diviLayer=diviLayer
        self.userLayer84=userLayer84
        features=[]

        Processing.initialize()

        general.runalg('qgis:selectbylocation', self.userLayer84, self.diviLayer, u'intersects',0.000001,0)
        self.userLayer84.invertSelection()
        number=self.userLayer84.selectedFeatureCount()

        for feature in self.userLayer84.selectedFeatures():
            attributes=[feature['Lokaliz'],feature['Zadanie'],feature['Projekt'],feature['Wykonawca'],feature['X'],feature['Y'],feature['h'],feature['Azymut'],feature['Dokl'],feature['KmEt'],feature['Km2Et'],feature['Poloz'],feature['Domiar'],feature['Nr_dz'],feature['Obr'],feature['JE'],feature['Pow'],feature['Woj'],feature['Data'],feature['Czas'],feature['xtrPhtC'],feature['xtrComC'],feature['xtrAudC'],feature['xtrFilC'],feature['NazwaRap'],feature['Sciezka']]
            feat=QgsFeature()
            feat.setAttributes(attributes)
            feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(QgsPoint(float(feature['Y']),float(feature['X']))))
            features.append(feat)

        return [features,number]

    [features,number]=self.selectFeatures(self.diviLayer,self.userLayer84)

    self.diviLayer.startEditing()
    self.diviLayer.dataProvider().addFeatures(features)
    self.diviLayer.commitChanges()
```

It seems like the signal is not emitted? Has anyone of you had a similar problem? Or maybe you know, where I'm making mistake.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to one of the QGIS developers ([@MatthiasKuhn](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9839/matthias-kuhn)) in his website [OPENGIS.ch](http://opengis.ch/2015/08/12/with-edit-layer/), he suggests to completely avoid `dataProvider()` methods as he lists the following (emphasis mine):

- You cannot undo them easily
- They generate one request per call what may reduce performance
- **They do not emit internal signals for map redraws and other refreshes of the user interface**
- They do not take uncommitted changes into account so the python changes will get overwritten by the user when he commits the layer changes

I think the third bullet point states that the `dataProvider()` method will not emit any signals (I could be wrong).

---

In any case, it is suggested to instead use the `with edit(layer):` method. So you could try replacing your last three lines:

```
self.diviLayer.startEditing()
self.diviLayer.dataProvider().addFeatures(features)
self.diviLayer.commitChanges()
```

With this:

```
with edit(self.diviLayer):
    self.diviLayer.addFeatures(features)
```

Note that you may need to import the `edit` method into your plugin using:

```
from qgis.core import edit
```

Comment: thank you very much! Now it is working :) And I remember not to use dataProvider() in the future. :)

Comment: @Olaniag - Most welcome, glad you got it to work! And I also have to remember to try and avoid `dataProvider()` :)